How can I find the Russell-Saunders terms symbols for states with the orbital angular momentum L=0 and spin S=5/2
My approach was as follows, but it appears to be incorrect.
 = 2.5
So the multiplicity should be 2s+1 = 6
 = 0, which corresponds to the letter "S".
Therefore, the term symbol is: ${^6S}$.

You seem to build the RS symbol correctly. What is your doubt?
